# Gnome-terminal vim gruvbox

Tags: gnome-terminal, vim, vim-plugin

Just installed gruvbox color scheme for Vim on Ubuntu, but the color scheme is not fully supported in the terminal. It works fine on a fedora box. Do I need any additional settings?

Comment: What exactly you mean with "not fully supported in the terminal" you mean the Gnome terminal colors? The vim colors? Something else?

Comment: Yes vim uses Gnome terminal colors and the value was 8 in my vim. So my vim theme didn't support it since it needed at least 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your terminal supports 256 colours then set this in your .vimrc `se t_Co=256` 
If your not sure then set this in your .vimrc `se t_Co=16`

---

### *Explanation:*

Getting consistent colors in different terminals is challenging because different terminals support different numbers of colors.

I ran this command on my vim which showed me the current colour setup  `:echo &t_Co`
This returned 8. Most themes in vim need more colours than 8.

Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_GUI_color_settings_in_a_terminal